# Using JedisPool with Tomcat, resources not being returned back to pool

Tags: java, tomcat, jersey, jedis

Looking at the output of `redis client list`, I see there are 600 active clients at the moment, and it continues to grow. Here's a snippet of output:

`id=285316 addr=x.x.x.x:55699 fd=14131 name= age=53055 idle=53029 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=0 qbuf-free=0 obl=0 oll=0 omem=0 events=r cmd=sismember
id=285317 addr=x.x.x.x:55700 fd=14132 name= age=53055 idle=53050 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=0 qbuf-free=0 obl=0 oll=0 omem=0 events=r cmd=sismember`

Here's my code:

*Listener.java*:

```
import com.sun.jersey.api.model.AbstractResourceModelContext;
import com.sun.jersey.api.model.AbstractResourceModelListener;

import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

@Provider
public class Listener implements AbstractResourceModelListener {

    @Override
    public void onLoaded(AbstractResourceModelContext modelContext) {
        RedisManager.getInstance().connect();
    }

}
```

*RedisManager.java*:

```
import redis.clients.jedis.Jedis;
import redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool;
import redis.clients.jedis.JedisPoolConfig;

public class RedisManager {
    private static final RedisManager instance = new RedisManager();
    private static JedisPool pool;

    private RedisManager() {
    }

    public final static RedisManager getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public void connect() {
        JedisPoolConfig poolConfig = new JedisPoolConfig();
        poolConfig.setMaxTotal(5000);
        poolConfig.setTestOnBorrow(true);
        poolConfig.setTestOnReturn(true);
        poolConfig.setMaxIdle(50);
        poolConfig.setMinIdle(1);
        poolConfig.setTestWhileIdle(true);
        poolConfig.setNumTestsPerEvictionRun(10);
        poolConfig.setTimeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis(60000);
        pool = new JedisPool(poolConfig, "redis_hostname");
    }

    public void release() {
        pool.destroy();
    }

    public Jedis getJedis() {
        return pool.getResource();
    }

    public void returnJedis(Jedis jedis) {
        pool.returnResourceObject(jedis);
    }
}
```

*APIServlet.java*:

```
@Path("/")
public class APIService {

    @GET
    @Path("/lookup")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getMsg(@QueryParam("email") String email,
                           @QueryParam("pretty") String pretty
    ) throws JSONException {
        Jedis jedis = RedisManager.getInstance().getJedis();
        if (jedis.sismember("inprocess", email)) {
            RedisManager.getInstance().returnJedis(jedis);
            return Response.status(202).entity("{\"status\":202, " +
                    "\"processing\":{\"type\":\"Lookup performed\", " +
                    "\"message\":\"We're performing analysis on this " +
                    "record. Result should be ready in a few minutes" +
                    ".\"}}").build();
        }

        Person person = new Person();
        person.lookup(person);
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(person);
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonString);        
        jsonObj.remove("objectID");
        jsonObj.remove("data_quality");
        jsonObj.put("status", 200);

        RedisManager.getInstance().returnJedis(jedis);

        if (!jsonObj.isNull("name") && !jsonObj.get("name").equals("")) {
            if (hasPretty) {
                return Response.status(200).entity(jsonObj.toString(4))
                    .build();
            }
            return Response.status(200).entity(jsonObj.toString()).build();
         }

         return Response.status(404).entity("{\"status\":404, " +
                "\"error\":{\"type\":\"Data Not Found.\", " +
                "\"message\":\"We were not able to find data " +
                "on this email.\"}}").build();
    }
}
```

*Maven Dependencies*:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
        <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.2</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

The Listener creates an instance of RedisManager to be used throughout the application--this should happen only once, on startup (note: I have no idea how to call destroy on shutdown, which would be nice to know). Throughout the program, this instance of JedisPool is used in Jersey routes, as shown in APIServlet.java. In the route, I get a JedisPool resource, then before I return on any part of the route, I return the resource.

What is happening is that the resource does not seem to be returned (or my understanding of the pool is wrong). After a period of time, the connections to my Redis instance grow to the maxTotal of 5,000, and then I start getting errors "could not get a resource from the pool," and Tomcat dies.

A few things I've noticed:

1. There seems to be a large amount of ESTABLISHED https connections that stick around (not 100% sure on this, but it seems to be the case).
2. All Redis clients that are idle (well, nearly all anyway) have a cmd of sismember.

*NOTE*: I've not included the full APIService.java code because I'm really not allowed to do so. The snippet I included does give the overall gist of the code. I am returning throughout the APIService.java code (return 404, return 429, etc), and before each return I make sure I am returning the resource to the pool.

Finally, here's the stacktrace:

```
10-Feb-2016 08:04:23.161 SEVERE [http-nio-443-exec-14] com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.mapMappableContainerException The RuntimeException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
 redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool
        at redis.clients.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:50)
        at redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool.getResource(JedisPool.java:86)
        at co.talentiq.api.APIService.getMsg(APIService.java:63)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor52.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:699)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:521)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1096)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:674)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: If you already have pool initialized do not create a new one:

```
public class RedisManager {
...
public void connect() {
    if(pool != null) {
        System.out.println("Already exists");
        return;
    }
    JedisPoolConfig poolConfig = new JedisPoolConfig();
    ...
```

Second ... Do you have exceptions in your logs from getMsg method?

```
public Response getMsg(@QueryParam("email") String email,
                       @QueryParam("pretty") String pretty
```

You should have all work with pooled resources being wrapped into try-catch-finally and always return resource in finally block. NB: make sure not to return resource (jedis in this case) to pool twice.

```
Jedis jedis;
try {
    jedis = RedisManager.getInstance().getJedis();
    ...
} finally {
    if (jedis != null) {
       RedisManager.getInstance().returnJedis(jedis);
       jedis = null;
    }
}
```

Btw: you can create a small AutoCloseable wrapper around your jedis get/return code and use java try with resources - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Code snippet with try-with-resource

```
public void release() {
    pool.destroy();
}
public static class JedisWrapper implements AutoCloseable {   
    private final JedisPoolConfig pool;
    private final Jedis jedis;
    public JedisWrapper(JedisPoolConfig pool, Jedis jedis) {
        this.pool = pool;
        this.jedis = jedis;
    }
    public Jedis get() {
        return jedis;
    }
    @Override
    public void close() {
        pool.returnResourceObject(jedis);
    }
}
public JedisWrapper getJedis() {
    return new JedisWrapper(pool, pool.getResource());
}
// you can delete this method
public void returnJedis(Jedis jedis) {
    pool.returnResourceObject(jedis);
}
```

And later in usage place

```
public Response getMsg(@QueryParam("email") String email,
                       @QueryParam("pretty") String pretty
) throws JSONException {
   try(JedisWrapper jw = ...) {
      Jedis jedis = jw.get();
      ...
   }
```

Comment: Is there a difference between pool.returnResourceOjbect() and pool.close()? From what I've been reading, pool.close() is the proper way to do things, but from my understanding of the pool, it would seem you'd just want to return the resource so that it can be reused. I'm currently implementing your suggestions and will be testing shortly. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: @FranzKafka pool.returnObject - will return single taken object, pool.close will close the pool and all objects that are registered within the pool. I updated answer with a sample how you can convert your code to autoclose approach. Sample created in 3 minutes using notepad. I think you can come with better one.